# Derivation in Sobolev space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, schwartz-distributions, derivations

Let $f\in W^{1,\infty}(]0,T[)$ $(0<T\le\infty)$ such that
$f(x)>0$ a.e. $x\in\mathopen]0,T[$ and let
$$g(x)=e^{-\int_0^x \frac{ds}{f(s)}}$$
Formally $g' = -\frac{1}{f}g$.
How can I justify this derivation?

Thanks

Comment: If you replace $f$ with its continuous version $f_1$, then $g$ is unchanged and it is $C^1$.

Comment: $f$ is Lipschitz-continuous.

Comment: Thanks to  Giorgio Metafune and  Bazin